# Does a symplectic group act on a tensor power of a spin representation?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, invariant-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}$More specifically, let $S_k$ be the spin representation of $\Spin(2k+1)$.
Then is there are action of $\Sp(2r-2)$ on $\bigotimes^{2r}S_k$ which commutes
with the action of $\Spin(2k+1)$?

I am not asking for a duality. That is, I do not require that each isotypic vector
space is an irreducible representation of $\Sp(2r-2)$.

The motivation is that the space of invariant tensors in $\bigotimes^{2r}S_k$ looks like
the irreducible representation of $\Sp(2r-2)$ with highest weight $k\omega_{r-1}$.
For instance, for $k=1$, both vector spaces have dimension given by the Catalan numbers $C_r = \frac{1}{r+1}\binom{2r}{r}$. More generally, for arbitrary $k$ the dimension of both of these spaces is
$$ \prod_{1\leq i \leq j \leq r-1} \frac{i+j+2k}{i+j} $$
which is the number of so-called "*$k$-fans of nested Dyck paths of semilength $r$*" (see, e.g., Section 3.1.6 of [Federico Ardila - Algebraic and geometric methods in enumerative combinatorics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2562)).

Comment: As mentioned in the bounty message, I would be interested in any algebraic explanation of the numerical coincidence of the dimensions of the spaces discussed in Bruce's question. Does some version of Howe duality apply here?

Comment: (For an explanation of a similar, well-known numerical "coincidence," but for $SL_n$ and $GL_m$, using Howe duality, see: https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/08/10/the-ubiquity-of-howe-duality/.)